# Laravel 5.7 eloquent update/delete multiple records

Tags: php, laravel-5

My table structure is like this:

```
invoices: 

        id, title, desciption, total_amount, --

products: 

        id, name, price, --

invoice_products

        id, invoice_id, product_id, --
```

- One invoice can have multiple products, so,
- I created an invoice with products, then data fills according to above DB structure.
- When i update invoice (let say invoice_id = 2 ), then, i am confused what is the best way to update "invoice_products" table.
- My approach is ( for "invoice_products" table):

  - delete * from invoice_products where invoice_id=2;
  - then insert modified products again.
- I think this is not good approach, as i am force deleting the rows in "invoice_products" and again inserting new updated products.
- is there any way to do via eloquent ?

Comment: Are you using Laravel relations?

Comment: Are you making many to many relationship ?You can use Laravel sync function

Comment: why are you [ delete * from invoice_products where invoice_id=2;  ] ?? You can do an update query. What you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think invoice_products is pivot table. You should use sync method.

```
$productIds = [1,2,3];
$Invoice->products()->sync($productIds);
```

Also in your invoice Model the relationship should be like this

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Invoice::class, 'invoice_products', 'invoice_id', 'product_id');
}
```

[More Details](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel many to many relation to achieve this functionality:

**Invoice Model**

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'invoice_products');
}
```

**Product Model**

Though it is not required here but you can use this to get invoice for related products.

```
public function invoices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'invoice_products');
}
```

To update the existing data you can use `sync` method:

```
$products = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$invoice->products()->sync($products);
```

You can read more about relationship over https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships